# Detecting activity launching inside application

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle

I'm trying to realize functionality for login launched activities names. I don't want to add checking in every activity. Short time ago i saw that it's possible to realize something like "activity lifecycle manager" inside application and catch callbacks like `activityCreated(...)` or `activityDestroyed(...)`. But unfortunately i forgot the exact name of that method/interface(i don't even remember what was that :( ) and i didn't manage to find something similar here.

So, can somebody tell me how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend the `Application` class and implement the `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` interface:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application implements ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

    // Various activity callbacks here

}
```

You can read about the callbacks [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html).

The above class will need to registered in the `<application>` tag of your manifest file under `android:name:""` property as `android:name:"MyApplication"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I was looking for!